# How to transfer POI layer from QGIS to OSMAnd?

Tags: qgis, point, vector-layer, point-of-interest, osmand

I've got a POI layer (vector layer with single-point geometry) in QGIS and would like to import these points to OSMAnd under "My Locations" including the attributes (like name of the point). How can I do that?

I tried SQLite, GeoPackage and GeoJSON, but always got two errors:

1. Firstly, OSMAnd complains that the layer does not contain waypoints and asks if I want to import it as track.
2. If I confirm, it then shows an error message like "Unexpected token (position: TEXT ...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I was able to import the POIs into OSMAnd as GPX format. However, **it was necessary to enable the `GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS` when exporting it in QGIS** in order to allow OSMAnd to import the string attributes properly.

Comment: I was just checking myself but nice, I am glad you solved it yourself :)

Comment: Many thanks for your help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to export to GPX (GPS eXchange) Format.

Check this: [Importing GPX in OSMAnd](https://osmand.net/help/faq.html#importing_gpx).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I tried it, but could not export the attributes with the points.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your data in order to have a better idea where the problem lies?

Comment: How does the original/exported attribute table looks like? How many / which type of attributes do they have?

Comment: There are 4 attributes, 3 of them are strings and 1 is an integer (UID). I don't care about the UID, but need to transfer at least the names (one of the string attributes).